# Como saber quando acontece a atualização do DOM virtual e do DOM real?

Tags: javascript, react, característica-linguagem, dom

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em React e reparei que usar múltiplos `setState()` seguidos causava o *render* do meu componente novamente, por exemplo:

```js
function MeuComponente() {
  console.log("Componente renderizado ");

  const [stateA, setStateA] = React.useState(false);
  const [stateB, setStateB] = React.useState(false);

  // useEffect apenas para atualizar o state uma única vez, não em todo render
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Atualizando state");
      setStateA(true);
      setStateB(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return <div ></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<MeuComponente />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Isso me preocupou um pouco porque eu achava que o React fazia um *batch* ("lote") dos `setState` para renderizar uma única vez. Fui pesquisar e encontrei no SOen uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575023/8839059) para isso. Destacando o principal ponto:

> Renderizar (no contexto React) e confirmar as atualizações virtuais do DOM no DOM real são questões diferentes. (...) O React pode fazer um *batch* das chamadas `setState` e atualizar o DOM do navegador com o novo estado final.

Partindo do ponto que isso realmente está certo, fiquei com essas dúvidas:

1. Como saber quando acontece a atualização do DOM virtual? Imagino que seja a cada retorno do componente, mas não tenho certeza.
2. Como saber quando acontece a atualização do DOM real?

Comment: A tua pergunta é no sentido de aprendizagem e compreensão dos mecanismos do DOM virtual ou tens código que queres correr quando o DOM for alterado?

Comment: Aprendizagem. O máximo que farei é usar isso para detectar componentes que estão sendo atualizados excessivamente no DOM. Por exemplo, colocando um `console.log` na atualização, mas não precisa ser uma solução via código, pode ser através de uma extensão também tipo React Developer Tools